# C# Action/Delegate makes wcf channel become faulted when non existent method is called

Tags: c#, wcf, exception, delegates, callback

I have a callback service in wcf which looks like this :

```
[ServiceContract(CallbackContract = typeof(IMyCallbacks), Namespace = "MyNamespace")]
public interface IMyService
{
  [OperationContract]
  bool subscribe();

  [OperationContract]
  bool unsubscribe();
}

public interface IMyCallbacks
{
  [OperationContract(IsOneWay=true)]
  void onNewCallback(int iValue);
}

[ServiceBehavior(InstanceContextMode=InstanceContextMode.Single, ConcurrencyMode=ConcurrencyMode.Multiple)]
public class MyService : IMyService
{
    Action<int> DelegateOnNewCallback { get; set; }
    public bool subscribe()
    {
      try
      {
        var wClient = OperationContext.Current.GetCallbackChannel<IMyCallbacks>();
        DelegateOnNewCallback += wClient.onNewCallback;
      }  
      catch (Exception iEx)
      {
        Console.Writeline(iEx.Message);
        return false;
      }
      return true;
    }

    public bool unsubscribe()
    {
      try
      {
        var wClient = OperationContext.Current.GetCallbackChannel<IMyCallbacks>();
        DelegateOnNewCallback -= wClient.onNewCallback;
      }
      catch (Exception iEx)
      {
        Console.Writeline(iEx.Message);
        return false;
      }
      return true;
    }

    // This function is called really often
    public void CallingFunction(int iValue)
    {
       try
       {
         DelegateOnNewCallback(iValue);
       }
       catch (Exception ex)
       {
          Console.Writeline(ex.Message);
       }
    }
}
```

On the client side, upon loading, I make a subscribe to the callback and print the value I receive. When the client is closed, I call the unsubscribe method. The Service is independent from the client and is never destroyed in the process.

My problem is encountered when a client process is destroyed and the unsubscribe method is not called. Every subsequent client won't receive the callback because the Wcf channel is in a faulted state. Every time CallingFunction is called, I receive the exception :

```
The communication object, System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel, cannot be used for communication because it has been Aborted.
```

I believe it is because, since unsubscribe wasn't called properly DelegateOnNewCallback still try to call the destroyed client's method which is now unexistent.
In that particular case, I would expect to receive the exception through my Try/Catch however, I wouldn't expect the service to go in faulted state.

The behavior I would want is, when CallingFunction is called, it would try to call every method DelegateOnNewCallback contains and if a method doesn't exist anymore, silently remove it from the list and continue invoking the subsequent methods.

How can I achieve this ?